# Selenium IDE - Unable to Convert the recorded case from HTML to Non HTML one by one sequencially

Tags: ide, selenium

Steps:

1. Record 5 Test Cases.
2. Open Test suite.
3. Select the 1st case and goto Option --> Format --> JUnit4 (Converted properly)
4. Copy the source.
5. Select the 2nd Case.

It shows Junit and HTML all mixed up. If I close the selenium IDE and open it again it allows me to convert 1 case. i.e i need to restart the IDE for each case conversion. It seems to be a bug in Selenium IDE.

I need to convert hundreds of cases. Are there any alternate method to convert cases quickly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should file a bug report about this if one doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium now shows that it does not recommend changing the format from HTML to copy paste it. It recommends instead to export them as new files, which does work fine. The problem with this, and with what you were doing, is that it is quite slow. However, somebody (not me) created an addon to help with batch exporting of IDE files into whatever format the IDE supports. I only tested it with TestNG, but it worked like a charm for me. Download link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/test-suite-batch-converter-sel/